# Joining two data frames and repeating values by group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to add a new variable (Day) to my df to indicate the first day an event occurs. For each batch the day value should be repeated until a new batch is listed.
I've added some dummy data below. How can I do this?

```
df <- tibble(Batch=c(rep(123,5), rep(345,5)), Month = rep(seq(5),2))
df_day <- tibble(Batch= c(123,345), Day= c(3,6))
```

Comment: `merge(df, df_day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

standard `left_join` should work

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df,df_day, by = "Batch")
```